# Computing preference values in Apache Mahout

Tags: java, machine-learning, mahout, recommendation-engine, mahout-recommender

I am trying to learn Apache mahout, very new to this topic. I want to implement user-based recommender. For this, after exploring on the internet I have found some samples like below,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            int userId = 2;

            DataModel model = new FileDataModel(new File("data/mydataset.csv"), ";");
            UserSimilarity similarity = new PearsonCorrelationSimilarity(model);
            UserNeighborhood neighborhood = new NearestNUserNeighborhood(2, similarity, model);
            UserBasedRecommender recommender = new GenericUserBasedRecommender(model, neighborhood, similarity);

            List<RecommendedItem> recommendations = recommender.recommend(userId, 3);
            for (RecommendedItem recommendation : recommendations) {
                logger.log(Level.INFO, "Item Id recommended : " + recommendation.getItemID() + " Ratings : "
                        + recommendation.getValue() + " For UserId : " + userId);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Exception in main() ::", e);
        }
```

I am using following dataset which contains userid, itemid, preference value respectively,

```
1,10,1.0
1,11,2.0
1,12,5.0
1,13,5.0
1,14,5.0
1,15,4.0
1,16,5.0
1,17,1.0
1,18,5.0
2,10,1.0
2,11,2.0
2,15,5.0
2,16,4.5
2,17,1.0
2,18,5.0
3,11,2.5
3,12,4.5
3,13,4.0
3,14,3.0
3,15,3.5
3,16,4.5
3,17,4.0
3,18,5.0
4,10,5.0
4,11,5.0
4,12,5.0
4,13,0.0
4,14,2.0
4,15,3.0
4,16,1.0
4,17,4.0
4,18,1.0
```

In this case, it works fine, but my main question is I have the different set of data which don't have preference values, which contains some data based on that I am thinking to compute preference values. Following is my new dataset,

```
userid  itemid  likes   shares  comments
1        4       1      20      3
2        6       18     20      12
3        12      10     2       20
4        7       0      20      13
5        9       0      2       1
6        5       5      3       2
7        3       9      7       0
8        1       15     0       0
```

My question is how can I compute preference value for a particular record based on some other columns such as likes, shares, comments etc. Is there anyway to compute this in mahout?

Answer (score 2):

Yes- I think your snippet is from an older version of Mahout, but what you want to use is the Correlated Co Occurrence recommender. The CCO Recommender is multi-modal (allows user to have various inputs).

There are CLI Drivers, but I'm guessing you want to code, there is a Scala tutorial [here](http://mahout.apache.org/docs/latest/tutorials/cco-lastfm/)

In the tutorial I think it recommends 'friends' based on genres tagged and artists 'liked', as well as your current friends.

Comment: Could you suggest any java based example for a reference

Comment: Not for "new" Mahout- which runs on Spark/Flink/H2O and uses a mathematically expressive Scala DSL.  I've heard there are some grad students somewhere working on Java implementations, but I don't know who or where. Best I can tell you is write the function in Scala, and import the jar :/

Comment: Can you suggest some links to start with Scala recommender, I am very new to Scala..

Comment: I learned from Dean Wampler's book and just sort of hacking at it.  If you know Java, it's pretty simple just removes a lot of boiler plate.  https://www.amazon.com/Programming-Scala-Scalability-Functional-Objects/dp/0596155956

Answer (score 2):

As @rawkintrevo says, Mahout has moved on from the older "taste" recommenders and they will be deprecated from Mahout soon.

You can build you own system from the CCO algorithm in Mahout [here](http://mahout.apache.org/docs/latest/algorithms/reccomenders/). It allows you to use data from different user behavior like "likes, shares, comments". So we call it multi-modal.

Or in another project we have created a full featured recommendation server based on Mahout, called the [Universal Recommender](http://actionml.com/universal-recommender). It is build on Apache PredicitonIO where the UR is a plugin called a Template. Together they deliver a nearly turnkey server that takes input and responds to queries. To get started easily try the [AWS AMI](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B01N310FF0) that has the whole system working. Some other methods to install are shown [here](http://actionml.com/docs).

This is all Apache licensed OSS, but Mahout no longer can really provide a production ready environment, Mahout does algorithms but you need a system around it. Build your own or try the PredictionIO based one. Since everything is OSS you can tweak things if needed.

Comment: how is your Universal recommender different from combining Apache prediction IO and mahout to build a full recommender ?